# Variations in variable expansion in bash between CentOS versions

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, sed

EDIT: @steeldriver in the comments pointed to this being a bug in some versions of visudo in processing EDITOR=, [ [Bug 942 - visudo fails if $EDITOR contains quotes](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=942) ] - the correlation to centos versions was happenstance.

I have been writing an internal installer script and came across a behavior I don't know how to explain.

#### Cent6

```
$ _sudoers_search_string="someuser ALL="
$ _sudoers_entry="someuser ALL= NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/bin/someprogram"
# ADD line to sudoers file
$ echo "${_sudoers_entry}" | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo 1>/dev/null
# REMOVE line
$ sudo EDITOR="sed -i -e '/.*${_sudoers_search_string}/d'" visudo
```

This works fine. I was then testing and on Cent7, I ran into the following error with that code:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
```

And in experimenting to find working code:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated address regex
```

Seemingly no combination of quoting and escaping was working until I made the following changes:

#### Cent7 (changed lines needed to get it working shown)

```
$ _sudoers_search_string="someuser\sALL="
...
$ sudo EDITOR="sed -i -e /.*${_sudoers_search_string}/d" visudo
```

My question(s): Why does it behave like this? (And is there code that will work for both versions of CentOS and bash?)

```
Cent6 = GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Cent7 = GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: It seems that trying to stuff all that into EDITOR just doesn't work: it seems that when visudo actually invokes $EDITOR, the single quotes are not respected.

Comment: The difference i snot in the variable expansion, but in how `$EDITOR` is used by `visudo`.

Comment: ... perhaps [Bug 942 - visudo fails if $EDITOR contains quotes](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=942) and you're seeing sudo versions before and after the fix?

Comment: I'm surprised that sed command ever worked.  The unescaped `/`s in `/usr/bin/someprogram` would break the `sed` command.   BTW, does Centos use the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory (would require a line like `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d` in `/etc/sudoers`)?    That would allow you to just create a file in that directory to add a rule, or delete the file to remove it - but you have to be extremely careful not to break sudo with a bad rule.

Comment: @steeldriver after testing - I am pretty sure your answer is correct. Updating might be impractical, but it gives me options to just make different code paths. If you want, please submit as the answer and I will mark it as such. Ty again